# is there a way to turn [0, -2, 1, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, 4, -6] into [0, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, -6]

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop, primes

In short, I had an assignment problem where  my final output should be a list of numbers, However in some cases, I have the good numbers in my list but just in the wrong order.  I don't want to change my entire code since it is quite long. Thus, I was wondering if there is a trick, function or something that I can use where I can sort the list in a ascending manner however it doesn't put the negative numbers first.
For example,  turn [0, -2, 1, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, 4, -6] into [0, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, -6]
Another example, turn [0, 1, 5, 9, -2, 2, -5, -9, -1] into [0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -5, 5, -9, 9]
Another example, turn [12,-12] into [-12,12]
Here you can see that its sorted in an ascending manner but its start from 0 and not from a negative number.

Comment: The duplicate it's technically not correct as OP want to sort ensuring that the negative values come first in case of a tie on the absolute value.

Comment: use this for your solution https://pastebin.com/Un5DenWB

Comment: OP dont want to change his entire code, just need a way to solve problem, i guess provided solution are right but not as per OP requirements, voting for reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```py
lst = [0, -2, 1, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, 4, -6]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x)))
```

output

```
[0, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, -6]
```

Basically you sort the items based on two priorities: first the absolute value of the numbers so that `2` and `-2` come next to each other. Also you mentioned, you want `-2` to come before `2`. The second item of the tuple does this. You are actually comparing tuples. First items are equal so comparison continues to the second items(ascending order):

```py
lst = [(2, 2), (2, -2)]
print(sorted(lst)) # [(2, -2), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the key parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with a tuple of the absolute value and the value itself. This will thus sort by the absolute and in case of tie, put the negative number first.

```
out = sorted(your_lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x))
```

Output on the first example:

```
[0, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, -6]
```

If you want to sort in place:

```
your_lst.sort(key=lambda x: (abs(x), x))
```